# Twitter/Facebook Like URLs ( Pages, UserNames and About Page ) htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Okay, Here are three Facebook URLs:

```
http://facebook.com/about [A Facebook Page]
http://facebook.com/zuck [Zuckerberg's Profile]
http://facebook.com/like [About Facebook Like Button]
```

If I have two pages:

```
http://example.com/user.php?u=[username]
http://example.com/page.php?p=[pagename]
```

I have successfully rewritten the user.php as http://example.com/[username] but after that when I use the same code for page, and try to access a page like http://example.com/[pagename], a userpage (404 page, because no user with that name exists but a page does) appears. So, What should I do to remove this conflict.

NOTE: I don't want to use URLs like http://example.com/user/Username and http://example.com/page/PageName. Please Help.

Comment: Could you post your htaccess code? Anyway you could write that logic into PHP not into htaccess. htaccess would only pass parameters to parsed by php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite all urls to a separate php file that detects whether the parameter is a username, or page name. The php should look something like this:

```
$name = $_GET['name']
if( userNameExists($name) )
  include('user.php');
else if ( pageNameExists($name) )
  include('page.php');
else
  include('404page.php');
```

You need to implement userNameExists() and pageNameExists() off course.